# How to link horizontal and vertical axes in matplotlib (similar to sharex/sharey)

Tags: python, matplotlib

`sharex` and `sharey` allow you to link, respectively, two x-axes and two y-axes together. What do I do, however, if **I want to link an x-axis to a y-axis** instead?

For example, I've projected an ellipsoid onto the xy (upper left), xz (lower left), and yz (upper right) axes such that these represent three sides of a cube:

[image: 3D ellipsoid projected onto three planes]

created using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax00 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax01 = fig.add_subplot(223, sharex=ax00)
ax10 = fig.add_subplot(222, sharey=ax00)
```

and when I zoom or resize, nearly all of the axes move and scale as I want them to — except that I want the horizontal axis of the upper-right plot to be linked to the vertical axis of the lower-left plot. I don't see any obvious way to do that.

Comment: Can you use `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim`?

Comment: @QuangHoang It won't persist between zooms. It works if I'm outputting a PDF or PNG, but not if I want interactivity.

Comment: It's not possible to use the sharing mechanism, because that [works independent](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/60214efe7ffcc490f53057fdd9a83e8a522df525/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L371-L372) for each axis. You can play around with a callback (`ax.connect("xlim_changed", callback)`), but it will be pretty cumbersome to get it straight.